# Ajustar fuente en grafico chartjs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Buenas estoy utilizando chartjs y necesito saber que propiedad se puede utilizar para modificar la orientación y fuente de un gráfico de barras para ser mas preciso del los datos del eje x como se muestra a continuación, ya que se ven con mucho espacio y demasiado grande, si alguien sabe se los agradecería
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
   const barsChartOptions = computed<ChartOptions<'bar'>>(() => ({
          indexAxis: 'x',
          scales: {
            x: {
                
              fontSize: 5,

              grid: {
                display: true,
                drawBorder: false,
              },
              beginAtZero: true,
            },
            y: {
              grid: {
                display: false,
                drawBorder: false,
              },
            },
          },
          plugins: {
           datalabels:{
            display: false,
           },
           
            legend: {
              display: false,
            },
          },
        }));

        const dataSet = distribucionUseCase.mapDataset(
          this.getDistribucion as IDistribucion[],
        );
        const dataValues = computed<ChartData<'bar'>>(() => ({
          labels: dataSet.labels,
          datasets: [
            {
              data: dataSet.datasets,
              backgroundColor: [
                '#32CD32',
                '#8B4513',
                '#FFFF00',
                '#4169E1',
                '#4169E1',
                '#800080',
                '#bef539',
                '#769b81',
              ],
              barThickness: 20,
              barPercentage: 1,
              categoryPercentage: 1,
             
              
            },
          ],
        }));
        const { barChartProps } = useBarChart({
          chartData: dataValues,
          options: barsChartOptions,
        });
        this.distribucionOptions = barChartProps;
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

Deebs colocar la siguiente configuración:

```
options:{
       scales: {
          xAxes: {
           ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 55,
                    font : {
                     size: 34
                    }
             },
          }
       }
```

Donde:

- `maxRotation`y `minRotation` son la rotación máxima y mínima respectivamente, chartJS ajustará la mejor opción dentro de ese rango. Si requieres una rotación fija simplemente repite el valor en ambos lados
- font es la estructura para configurar la fuente de este eje, más opciones en https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

EJEMPLO:

```js
const datos = [
    {
        "year": 2022,
        "total": 1973
    },
    {
        "year": 2021,
        "total": 4044
    },
    {
        "year": 2020,
        "total": 1000
    }
];

const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: datos.map(a=>a.year),
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Tareas Cerradas',
                data: datos.map(a=>a.total),
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                borderWidth: 2,
                borderRadius: 5,
                borderSkipped: false,
            }],
    },
    options:{
       scales: {
          xAxes: {
           ticks: {
                    maxRotation: 90,
                    minRotation: 55,
                    font : {
                     size: 34
                    }
             },
          }
       }
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:600px;height:400px">
   <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```